# Can we kill one of the activities with same sharedUserId?

Tags: android

Can we kill one of the activities with same sharedUserId on platform 2.1?
Just the one.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, since you have no `Activity` object on which to call `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new API to finish an activity:

ActivityManagerService.java:

```
    long callingId = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    ArrayList history = mHistory;
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = history.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                HistoryRecord r = (HistoryRecord) history.get(i);
                if (r.packageName.equals(packageName)) {
                    if (Config.LOGD)
                        Log.d(TAG, "  Force finishing activity "
                                + r.intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString());
                    if (null != r.app) {
                        r.app.removed = true;
                    }
                    r.app = null;
                    finishActivityLocked(r, i, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null, "uninstall");
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(callingId);
    }
```